# Animation with windows forms and datagrid using thread.sleep(int)

Tags: c#, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col", "col");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

When I run this code all the columns show up at one time after 5s not one by one every 1 second. Please help me, I don't want to use timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremly extremly nasty code, and you **Should** use timers.

However, if you insist on doing it this way, try to throw in a `Application.DoEvents()` (shudder) after the `Thread.Sleep(100);` line.

By the way, why do you not want to use timers? They are very easy to set up and will make this code much cleaner than it will end up this way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give the form a chance to redraw itself.

Call `Invalidate` and then `Update` before going to sleep.

Comment: I don't think Invalidate will work. Invalidate repaints the canvas when it gets some free time, and I don't think that will happen in the middle of the loop. I haven't tried, so I can't say for sure ;)

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen It usually does. Well, in fact, it does not have to, because it does not force synchronious paint, but [calling Update after Invalidate will cause synchronious paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx).